# Tkinter program does not behave as I think it should

Tags: python, tkinter

My counter will not stop. When I hit start for a 2nd time I want it to continue counting and not restart.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

Counter_Activation_Variable=3

def start():
    Counts=0
    Counter_Activation_Variable=0
    button.configure(text = "Stop", command=stop)  
    while Counter_Activation_Variable == 0:
        Counts = Counts+1
        Textbox.delete(1.0, END)
        Textbox.insert(END,(Counts))
    master.update()

def stop():
    Counter_Activation_Variable=5
    button.configure(text = "Start", command=start)
    master.update()

button = Button(master, text="Start",command=start, bg="grey")
button.pack(side='bottom', fill='none', expand=False, padx=4, pady=4)
master.title("Stopwatch")

Textbox = Text(master, height=1, width=175)
Textbox.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=4, pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Descriptive variable and method names would really help in this situation :)

Comment: what do you mean sorry if its obvious but im new to coding most of this I just peiced together from other sites and understood

Comment: I can figure out how your code functions, but using descriptive variable names such as "timer_status" instead of "a", or "seconds" instead of "x", really make programming glorious. This is a good tip since you're new :)

Comment: That `while` loop is never going to run. When you call `start()` Python isn't going to just magically go back up to your loop because you changed the value of `a`. I suggest learning more about functions and control flow first.

Comment: well I also added the while loop under start() and I couldnt press stop but it started the counter and changed the text to stop

Comment: def start():
  a=0
  button.configure(text = "Stop", command=stop)
  while a == 0:
    x = x+1
    T.insert(END, (x))

    print (x)
    master.update

Comment: thats how i did it at first if its any better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a two problems here. The bigger, more obvious one is a *scoping* problem.

The short answer is that you just need two extra lines to fix this.

```
def start():
 global Counter_Activation_Variable  # add this
 Counts=0
...
def stop():
 global Counter_Activation_Variable  # and this
 Counter_Activation_Variable = 5
```

If you don't do this, the variable `Counter_Activation_Variable` *inside* the `start()` method will refer to a different variable that also happens to have the name `Counter_Activation_Variable` inside of the `stop()` method, which is totally separate from a *third* variable in the global scope also named `Counter_Activation_Variable`.

This is because Python allows you to reference variables only in specific areas, called scopes. So a variable defined in a function only exists inside that function. If you want to write to a global variable, you have to explicitly mark it as a global. (Python lets you read directly from a global variable without declaring it inside the function first)

The second function, which I alluded to earlier, is a *threading* problem. I'm thinking that the while loop in `start()` will occupy all of the computation time and so, even when the button is clicked again, the `stop()` method may not execute correctly.

However, I don't know enough about TKinter to know if it handles that kind of GUI multi-threading for you -- it very well could.

Comment: I also used the global on 'Counts' making start resume and not restart the counter